# Why wont this print any output? (c programming language)

Tags: c

Not sure why nothing is coming out, compiler finds no errors, it just runs and terminates a few seconds later, no output.

I'll give the source code and the input file's text.

Source code:
letterArray.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* displays a histogram of the frequencies 
of letters in input */
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int nletter[26];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
        nletter[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 
'c' || c == 'd' || c == 'e' || c == 'f' || 
c == 'g' || c == 'h' || c == 'i' || c == 
'j' || c == 'k' || c == 'l' || c == 'm' || 
c == 'n' || c == 'o' || c == 'p' || c == 
'q' || c == 'r' || c == 's' || c == 't' || 
c == 'u' || c == 'v' || c == 'w' || c == 
'x' || c == 'y' || c == 'z')
            ++nletter[c];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c 
== '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else 
            ++nother;

        printf("Letter: a b c d e f g h i j 
k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
\nOccurences:");        
        for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
            printf(" %d", nletter[i]);
        printf("\nwhite space = %d, other = 
%d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Text input: input.txt

```
    abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyzz
```

I'm pretty new to c, and to programming in general. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to press `CTRL+D` after giving input `abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyzz` as when you press `Ctrl+d`then it detects `EOF`.

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The while loop terminates when it reaches the end of the input file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm running the executable in command prompt like this:     letterArray.exe < input.txt    Command prompt doesn't do anything with ctrl+d

Comment: The control character for EOF in the Windows terminal is Ctrl+Z. Note: most people will assume that a developer will use a POSIX-compliant terminal, so you should mention it in your question if you are using the Windows terminal (only if relevant to the question, of course).

Comment: Possibly not your immediate problem, but you need to map `'a'` to `0`, `'b'` to `1`, .... At the moment you're doing `++nletter['a'];` but `nletter['a']` does not exist.

Comment: For a more beautiful program, check the [functions declared in `<ctype.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/ctype.h.html).

Comment: @pmg I think I understand what you mean, but I'm not sure how to do that. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Ever thought of `if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') { /* do your stuff */ }` rather than that long conflagration of `c == 'a' || c == 'b' || ...`? Even better, include `ctype.h` and just check `if (islower(c)) { /* do your stuff */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler should be warning you that the index for your `nletter` array will be out of bounds -- which will invoke *Undefined Behavior*..

The problem causing you to write beyond the bounds of `nletter` is your failure to insure the indexing you use runs `0-25`. Specifically you attempt:

```
        ++nletter[c];
```

where `c` will contain the ASCII value from `'a' - 'z'` (or `97 - 122`) see: [ASCIItable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/). That is well above the usable **indexes available** (`0 - 25`) resulting from your declaration of: `int nletter[26];` (recall, arrays are indexed from `0` to `n-1` in C).

To prevent writing beyond the bounds of your array, you need to normalize the indexes such that `'a'` will correspond to `0` and `'z'` will correspond to `25`. You do this by simply subtracting `'a'` from the value of `c`, e.g.

```
        ++nletter[c - 'a'];
```

although I prefer the post-increment operator here, so:

```
        nletter[c - 'a']++;
```

(the choice of the increment operator is yours -- the result is the same)

Putting it altogether, and adding a few clean-ups as described in the comments below, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)     /* main() is a function that return type int */
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int nletter[26] = {0};      /* {0} will initialize nletter */

    nwhite = nother = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') 
            nletter[c - 'a']++; /* you want indexes from 0-25 */
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c== '\t')
            nwhite++;
        else 
            nother++;
    }

    printf ("Letter:     a b c d e f g h i j k "
            "l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z\n"
            "Occurences:");        

    for (i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
        printf ("%2d", nletter[i]);   /* use the field-width modifier to */
                                      /* insure output of 2 spaces per-int */

    printf("\nwhite space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);

    return 0;
}
```

(**Note:** you can simplify further by including `ctype.h` and checking `islower(c)` instead of `'a' <= c && c <= 'z'` and using `isspace(c)` instead of `c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c== '\t'`, but since your Question didn't specify whether you could use anything but `stdio.h` I left the manual checks in place.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
 $ echo "abcdefg hijklmnop qrstuv wxyzz" | ./bin/letterfreq
Letter:     a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
Occurences: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
white space = 4, other = 0
```

(if testing on windows, omit the quotation marks or you will see `other = 2`)

If you are just getting started, then always compile with "*warnings-enabled*" and read and fix all warnings -- do not accept code until it compiles cleanly -- *without a single warning*. That will catch most problems before you end up scratching your head for hours. For gcc/clang, that means adding, at minimum, `-Wall -Wextra` to your compile string (you can add `-pedantic` for a few more, and adding `-Wshadow` is helpful). For VS, use `/W3` -- the `/Wall` for VS contains quite a few non-code related suggestions as warnings.

A compile string for this code would look like:

**gcc**

```
 gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast -o letterfreq letterfreq.c
```

**VS**

```
cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /Feletterfreq /Tc letterfreq.c
```

In either case, the code should compile without warning.